# Navigating to screen on button click but it is navigating without the button press

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './home.dart';
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
Question({super.key});
TextEditingController durationController = 
TextEditingController();
TextEditingController lengthController = TextEditingController();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 180),
        child: const Text("enter the period duration",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      ),
      Card(
          child: TextField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          labelText: "period duration",
        ),
        controller: durationController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      )),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 180),
        child: const Text("enter the period length",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      ),
      Card(
          child: TextField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          labelText: "period length",
        ),
        controller: lengthController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      )),
      OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //ClearSession();
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
          },

          child: const Text("Submit")),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}
//my aim is on pressing the button , next screen have to appear and in next screen there should be 3 icon but instead of appearing new screen when hitting button , it is showing the icon page in Question widget

// next screen widget class is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
 const Home({super.key});
@override
State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
 }

  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(child: Icon(Icons.home)),
          Container(child: Icon(Icons.calendar_month)),
          Container(
            child: Text(" home button"),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

//my aim is on pressing the button , next screen have to appear and in next screen there should be 3 icon but instead of appearing new screen when hitting button , it is showing the icon page in Question widget

Comment: do you have any other place for navigation? current snippet seems ok,`await` may not be needed. It would be easier if you can provide a full minimal widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: use Navigator.pushReplacement

Comment: @LacticWhale, that isn't going to solve the issue !

Comment: Example code can't perform navigation without clicking because functionality located inside of the **onPressed** callback will be executed only after pressing this button. 

Something beyond this code happened. If you can share more details will be helpful

Comment: navigator.pushReplacement is not working

Comment: i have updated the code, can you see it again plz

Comment: @powerman23rus i have uploaded more details sir

Comment: @OMiShah I wasn't trying to solve the issue. It's just better to use one method than two.

Comment: thank you sir for the concern, but the problem was solved, it was my fault, I call the same home widget in the main. dart file, sorry for consuming your valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can potential problem if this is a first screen and you use the `pop` method then you will get an error because you have nothing to pop.

Try to check the first possibility of navigation poping like in the example below

```
OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {
        //ClearSession();
        if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
         }
         Navigator.pushReplacement(context, 
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
     },
     child: const Text("Submit"),
 ),
```

Comment: thank you for the concern, but the problem was solved, it was my fault, I call the same home widget in the main. dart file, sorry for consuming your valuable time